# Disconnect a Google/Android account from a phone number

Tags: security, gmail, lost-phone

I recently lost my phone for a few days and tried to sign into my Gmail account to let acquaintences know. Gmail wouldn't allow me to sign in, as it was an unfamiliar location, and the only ways I could confirm my account involved my phone and my phone number. How can I disconnect my Gmail account from my phone number to make sure this doesn't happen again?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of deleting your phone number I advice adding an additional recovery email.
But if you want to delete your phone number from your Google account, you have to go to myaccount.google.com and then select **access and security**, then select recovery phone. Finally enter your Gmail password, press edit and delete the phone number.